# Linq to Entities conditional WHERE

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities, iqueryable, anonymous-types

I'm currently running the following query:

```
var results = from c in _context.Cs
              join a in _context.Ca on c.Id equals a.CId
              where c.Status == "A"
              where c.CtId == ctId
              where c.FY == fYear
              where (a.PMId == lUserId || a.TLId == lInUserId)
              select new { c.Id, c.T, c.C, c.S } into x
              group x by new {x.Id, x.T, x.C, x.S} into g
              orderby g.Key.T, g.Key.C, g.Key.S
              select new { Id = g.Key.Id, T = g.Key.T, C = g.Key.C, S = g.Key.S}
```

Now I need to make the `where (a.PMId == lUserId || a.TLId == lInUserId)` line conditional on if lUserId != 0 (use it if not 0, ignore it if 0).

Normally, I would declare the variable `results` then set it in an if statement, but I have no idea how to define this data structure.  It shows as being defined as:

```
IQueryble<'a>

'a is new { int Id, string T, string C, string S}
```

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `||` operator in the query so if first condition is true, the second will not be evaluated and if first is false that is not equal to 0 second will be evaluated:

```
where lUserId ==0 || (a.PMId == lUserId || a.TLId == lInUserId)
```

Comment: That was way to simple.  Sometimes I cant see the forest for the trees. Sheesh!  Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is:

- use the condition `a.PMId == lUserId || a.TLId == lInUserId` if and only if `UserId != 0`
- Ignore that condition if `lUserId ==0`
  If I understand the requirement correctly, then `&&` will be the operator that you have to use here. since it will *skip checking the second condition* if the first condition is false(that is `UserId == 0`).

I think you are looking for this:

```
where (UserId != 0 && a.PMId == lUserId || a.TLId == lInUserId)
```